# Tag Rugby: 6 men a side, 4 on pitch, 2 subs. 40 minute game. How often to sub?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Playing a game of Tag Rugby tonight. We have 6 male players, of which 4 will always be on 
the pitch, with 2 subs.

The game lasts 40 minutes, 20 each half.

How long should each player get to play, and how could the subbing be done in a fair manner, regardless of player ability?

Thanks

Brian

Comment: Are you able to substitute freely?

Comment: Yes, any players any time

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to substitute freely, then you can divide the time evenly:
$$\frac{4 \text{ players in play} \cdot 40 \text{ minutes} }{ 6 \text{ players}}=26\frac{2}{3} \text{ minutes}.$$

Here is one schedule that could work:

Organize your team into pairs $A$, $B$, and $C$. We'll "cycle" through them.

- $0-13.3$ minutes: $A$ and $B$
- $13.3-26.6$ minutes: $B$ and $C$
- $26.6-40$ minutes: $A$ and $C$

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. But, the issue with this cycle is that it doesn't take the half time into account. Lets say we wanted to break that into two twenty minute halfs. Practically, it would make sense to have cycles that end at half time. I'll think on it

Comment: @BrianBishop If you want that, then just halve the intervals in the schedule that I've given you, and repeat for the second half.